# Too many Connection Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, schedule

i am developing an application using spring hibernate where i am generating hibernate session using HibernateUtil class.

```
  public class HibernateUtil {

private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

static {
    try {
        Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
        StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new StandardServiceRegistryBuilder().
                applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
        sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        // Log the exception. 
        System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
    return sessionFactory;
}
```

}

Now i wrote a schedule class in spring which request to server repeatedly .

```
 @Scheduled(fixedRate = 3000)
public void sendNotification() {
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm");
    Date currentDate = new Date();
    System.err.println("Current Date "+dateFormat.format(currentDate));

    List<ImageInfo> listImageInfo = imageInfoDao.getImageOfParticularDate(currentDate);
    if (listImageInfo.size() > 0) {

        List<User> listUser = userDao.getAppUser("1");
        for (ImageInfo imageInfo : listImageInfo) {
            for (User user : listUser) {
               pushNotification(user.getRegId(), pushGroupNumNotification(imageInfo.getGroupNum()),"POST");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

this is my Dao function

```
 public List getImageOfParticularDate(Date date) {
    List<ImageInfo> imageInfoList = new ArrayList<>();
    try {
        session = getSession();
        imageInfoList = session.createQuery("select img from ImageInfo img where img.active = 0 and  img.publishedTime <:publishedTime   ").setParameter("publishedTime", date).list();
        session.createQuery("update ImageInfo img set img.active = 1 where   img.active = 0  and  img.publishedTime <:publishedTime ").setParameter("publishedTime", date).executeUpdate();
    } catch (Exception ex) {

        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }

    return imageInfoList;
}
```

you can see i am getting hibernate session using a getSession() function.this is my getSession() function where i am getting session using HibernateUtil.

```
public Session getSession() {
    return HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
 }
```

Now since Scheduler request to server frequently after some time i am getting an exception "Too many connection".you can see i closed my session at end . How can i solve it??

Comment: are you closing the connections somewhere?

Comment: `session.close()` seems to be commented out, above; is it commented on the actual code, too?

Comment: No sir Haroldo_OK,It is not

Comment: I guess you are not using the spring support for hibernate so it can be that some connection is not correctly closed; i would leave connection and transaction management to spring